# How to abort the uploading through HTTPWebRequest correctly?

Tags: c#, multithreading, httpwebrequest

```
ImageFile currImage = (ImageFile)image;
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(BuildUrl(currImage.Meta));
req.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
req.Method = "POST";                                
req.ContentType = currImage.MimeType;
req.ContentLength = currImage.Meta.Length;

var fileStream = new FileStream(
                    currImage.Meta.FullName,
                    FileMode.Open,
                    FileAccess.Read, // Allows share file with other processes !important
                    FileShare.Read
                );

// Prepare to read the file and push it into request stream
using (BinaryReader fileReader = new BinaryReader(fileStream))
{
    using (Stream requestStream = req.GetRequestStream())
    {
        // Create a buffer for image data
        const int bufSize = 1024;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufSize];
        int chunkLength = 0;

        // Transfer data
        while ((chunkLength = fileReader.Read(buffer, 0, bufSize)) > 0)
        {
            IAsyncResult result = requestStream.BeginWrite(buffer, 0, chunkLength, null, null);

            // Check for cancellation here <-----
            if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {                               
                _logger.Info(String.Format("Uploading {0} was cancelled in process.", currImage.Meta.FullName));                                
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            }

            result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
            requestStream.EndWrite(result);
        }
    }
}

try
{
    // Read image ID from the response
    WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
    TextReader responseReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

    string imageId = responseReader.ReadToEnd();

    long id;
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(imageId) && !Int64.TryParse(imageId, out id))
        throw new Exception("Wrong response for an uploaded image");
}
catch (Exception exp)
{
    _logger.Error(String.Format("Unable to read ImageId answer: {0}", exp.ToString()));                 
}
```

I'm using this code to upload files to my server, but if there is a cancellation situation I get an error if cancellation is appeared in the middle of uploading process.

System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: The request was canceled. ---> System.IO.IOException: Cannot close stream until all bytes are written.
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.CloseInternal(Boolean internalCall, Boolean aborting)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.CloseInternal(Boolean internalCall, Boolean aborting)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.System.Net.ICloseEx.CloseEx(CloseExState closeState)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.IO.Stream.Close()
   at System.IO.Stream.Dispose()

How can I manage it correctly? I tried to call req.Abort() or requestStream.Close() manually before token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

I understand why this error is appeared, but I don't know how to say the system that it is ok - I want to break the connection down.

Comment: anybody? If I gave bad explanation, please, tell me. I'll rephrase it

Comment: It needs to tell vs not to catch it in the preferences